# Why I'm unable to install Eclipse using ubuntu-make on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, ppa, eclipse, ubuntu-make

I have `ubuntu-make` installed on my Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS system.

The Ubuntu Make was installed previously from [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-make) using [Ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make?action=recall&rev=8). So I have the following:

```
$ umake --version
18.05

$ which umake 
/usr/bin/umake

$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/umake
ubuntu-make: /usr/bin/umake

$ apt-cache policy ubuntu-make 
ubuntu-make:
  Installed: 18.05~xenial1
  Candidate: 18.05~xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 18.05~xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     16.02.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

It was working as expected until today when I tried to install Eclipse with it and got error:

```
$ umake ide eclipse
Choose installation path: /home/username/.local/share/umake/ide/eclipse
ERROR: Download page changed its syntax or is not parsable

Your currently installed version (18.05) differs from the latest release (20.04)
Many issues are usually fixed in more up to date versions.
To get the latest version you can read the instructions at https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error output indicated that currently installed 18.05 version of Ubuntu Make is outdated, so we need to upgrade it.

By visiting the https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make we can determine two possible solutions:

- use Ubuntu Make from Snappy

  In my current case this means the following process:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
  sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-make
  sudo apt-get install snapd

  snap install ubuntu-make --classic
  ```
- use other [new official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~lyzardking/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-make) as indicated in [Ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make?action=recall&rev=9)

  In my current case this means the following process:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```

Personally I want to avoid Snappy, so I have added new PPA to the system.
As the result Eclipse 20.03 got installed.